# How to update TTL for Couchbase Document?

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

At the time of updating the document, I need to change the TTL according to the value of a field.

Does Couchbase support changing TTL once the document is created?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not mutating the document other than resetting the TTL, use `touch`.

If you're mutating the document as well, use one of the overrides that allows you to also set the TTL on `replace` and `upsert`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can update the TTL of an existing document. Use the replace method which accepts doc id and a TTL value

```
client.replace(key, expiry, value [, persistTo] ,[ replicateTo])
```

Comment: can you please give sample working code? @Samar